# How to show the statistics in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

When i access my report page in moodle(3.5) i get this below error.

```
Statistics is currently in catchup mode. So far 31 day(s) have been processed and 76 are pending. Check back soon!
```

Moodle not showing the reports.Cron is working.

Comment: Have u checked here https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Statistics

Comment: @LewaBammyStephen yes i enabled the statistics. but nothing is showing